# Hide scikit-learn ConvergenceWarning: "Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data"

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using Python to predict values and getting many warnings like:

> Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as
> shown in:
> https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options:
> https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression
> n_iter_i = _check_optimize_result(
> C:\Users\ASMGX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model_logistic.py:762:
> ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1): STOP: TOTAL
> NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.

this prevents me from seeing the my own printed results.

Is there any way I can stop these warnings from showing?

Comment: You did not post any code or data, so kind of difficult to tell. What this means is that your data is not converging in the given limit.

Comment: @RecencyEffect I know what it means. I just want to hide it

Comment: Can you filter them with [warnings.filterwarnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings)-module to temporarily suppress warnings. Either all warnings or specific warnings.

In this case scikit-learn is raising a [`ConvergenceWarning`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.exceptions.ConvergenceWarning.html) so I suggest suppressing exactly that type of warning. That warning-class is located in `sklearn.exceptions.ConvergenceWarning` so import it beforehand and use the context-manager [`catch_warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings) and the function [`simplefilter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter) to [ignore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter) the warning, i.e. not print it to the screen:

```py
import warnings
from sklearn.exceptions import ConvergenceWarning

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=ConvergenceWarning)
    
    optimizer_function_that_creates_warning()
```

You can also ignore that specific warning globally to avoid using the context-manager:

```py
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=ConvergenceWarning)

optimizer_function_that_creates_warning()
```

I suggest using the context-manager though since you are sure about where you suppress warnings. This way you will not suppress warnings from unexpected places.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `solver` and `max_iter` to solve the problem...

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

clf=LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', max_iter=500000).fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Your answer looks good, but try to use code formatting for code snippets. This greatly increases the readability.